# How to modify the template

Tags: templates

I am new to latex, and I am using a template to write my thesis. The template is available [here](http://www.in.tum.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Studiengaenge/MSc_CSE/thesis/template.tar.gz) 
, The problem I met is that after every "part", there always a empty page, which also takes one page number. Also there is empty pages between "Outline of the thesis" and the main body, and so on. My question is how could I modify the template to control(delete) these empty pages. Which file should I modify? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not much users like to follow links to download it for themselves.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how should I post the template I am using now?

Comment: Assuming, it is not too large, just post it in your original question above, select it with the mouse and press `CTRL-K` to format it as code, before pressing *Save*

Comment: It's not just codes from one file, the thing is I don't know which file I should  modify.

Comment: If you are using a template, it is the template you should modify, I would say, if you are not satisfied how the setup is done there.

Comment: Thanks, I know I should modify the template. But the template contains a lot of files, and I don't know which file and which part should I modify.

Comment: I think you are right. Every parts of my thesis just start with an odd page number. Is this for duplex printing? What if I will print it only with one side? And seems it will let the title page of each part on the odd page, because it will put an empty page before the title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is not caused by your template but by the `scrbook`-class which is used in this template. The motivation behind this behaviour is that every new `part` starts on an odd page being on the right hand side in case of double sided printing.

In general this is a desired layout, however if you really, really want to get rid of these empty pages, you can add `oneside` to the class options

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
```

or in case of your template

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13,oneside]{scrbook}
```

[this line is probably to be found in your main `.tex` file]

Comment: Thank you very much, and also thanks to another person who answered me on the comment but I can not find it anymore :)

Comment: Glad it solved your problem! The comment you are revering to was also by my, but after looking at the template I decided to move it to this answer.